# Java AJAX server, how to zip JSON responses

Tags: java, json, http, zip, gzip

I have a large response which is a JSON object at least 88Kb, I am having problems receiving this data on the clients.

I would like to zip the content in the Java application and send back the zip, I've done this before when using PHP on the server to zip large content and the browser then unzips it.

At present the JSON string is built up in a StringBuilder object.  If this idea is flawed what else could I do?  The JSON object contains status information for a large system and I need frequent updates to be sent.

Edit...I've progressed the problem, if the size of the JSON is > 512 bytes then I pass the StringBuffer onto the function below:

```
    public StringBuilder zipStringBuilder(StringBuilder sbSource) {
        StringBuilder sbZipped = null;

        try {
            byte[] arybytSource = sbSource.toString().getBytes();
            byte[] arybytBuffer = new byte[ZIP_BUFFER];
            Deflater objDeflater = new Deflater();
            objDeflater.setInput(arybytSource);
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(arybytSource.length);
            objDeflater.finish();           
            while( !objDeflater.finished() ) {
                int intCount = objDeflater.deflate(arybytBuffer);
                baos.write(arybytBuffer, 0, intCount);
            }
            baos.close();
            sbZipped = new StringBuilder();         
            sbZipped.append(baos.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return sbZipped;
    }
```

The HTTP headers are as follows:

```
    HTTP/1.0 200
    Date: Fri Nov 13 14:47:06 GMT 2015
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
    Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT
    Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
    Keep-Alive: timeout=2, max=100
    Cache-Control: no-cache
    Pragma: no-cache
    Content-Encoding: zip
    Content-type: application/json;charset=utf-8
```

But I don't receive this or the browser doesn't understand it?

I've also tried:

```
    Content-Encoding: gzip
```

With same result.

Answer (score 0):

If your server is behind apache web server turn on the 
apache inflate command